# JavaFX memory not freed after deleting mesh

Tags: memory-management, javafx, garbage-collection

I have a javafx application with a 3D subscene that displays 3D objects. After import the objects are saved in a Trianglemesh and added to the scene in a Meshview.
What I noticed is when I import a 100mb+ 3D file the memory usage goes up a lot, as expected, however when I delete the meshview and trianglemesh the memory usage doesn't go down much.

I used visualvm to confirm that it is the used heap that doesn't go down much.
[image: memory issue] 
The first point is where a 300mb 3D file is added to the scene after being imported. The second point is where the meshview is removed from the scene and collected by GC.

After more investigation with IntelliJ's memory I confirmed that the references to the meshview and trianglemesh are gone. However a very large number of Vector3f and MeshVertex objects were still around. Those references are held by an instance of the [MeshTmpView class](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~ckyang/RT-29012/webrev.02/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/prism/impl/MeshTempState.java-.html)

Since that's a javafx internal class, is there a way to clear these caches?

Comment: On which Java version you have verified this?

Comment: Java version 1.8.0_92

Answer (score 0):

there is an already existing issue https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089605 which was closed as Won't fix with the reason "Application should use the new user-defined normals format for dynamic mesh to avoid high memory and CPU usage.", could you please check the attached test case with the report and let us know if it is the same issue that you are facing. If not kindly share the test case that help us to eveluate better.